# Instantiate Generic Type in C# class

Tags: c#, generics, instantiation

Pretty basic question in C#,

```
class Data<T>
 {
    T obj;

    public Data()
    {
      // Allocate to obj from T here
      // Some Activator.CreateInstance() method ?
      obj =  ???
    }
 }
```

How do i do this?

Comment: A follow up for someone who is interested in this.This is a major difference between C# Generics and C++ templates, we have to impose constraints on types for the compiler to recognize any properties of the type. Please read this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(VS.80).aspx#csharp_generics_topic4

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to create your own instance of T, then you need define a constraint `new()`

```
class Data<T> where T: new()
 {
    T obj;

    public Data()
    {
      obj =  new T();
    }
 }
```

If you want to pass in the obj then you need to allow it in the constructor

```
 class Data<T>
     {
        T obj;

        public Data(T val)
        {
          obj = val;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Answer is exactly what I was looking for too! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

YOU can use the [`new` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28VS.80%29.aspx) in your generic class definition to ensure T has a default constructor you can call. Constraints allow you to inform the compiler about certain behaviors (capabilities) that the generic parameter T must adhere to.

```
class Data<T> where T : new()
{
    T obj;

    public Data()
    {
        obj = new T();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help: http://pooyakhamooshi.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-instantiate-generic-type-with.html